# PHP - Retrieving Value from SimpleXMLElement Object and Keeping Decimal Places

Tags: php

I'm working with a SimpleXMLElement Object and retrieving amounts for invoices, some of which are negative. I've just noticed that when I insert those values into my database they have converted to a positive number and dropped the decimal places.

Here's an example of an invoice amount from the SimpleXMLElement Object:

```
[UnitAmount] => -13.50
```

I'm storing the invoice amount as follows:

```
$UnitAmount = $invoiceLineItem->UnitAmount;
```

If I do a var_dump($UnitAmount) I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#28 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "-13.50"
}
```

I've tried using the float and abs functions to return the value as a float but both of these are returning '-13.5' but I need to keep the 2 decimal places so need it to return '-13.50'.

Not sure what else to try to keep the original positive or negative value with all decimal places.

Comment: 1) why do you think that  '-13.5'  is positive? 2)you can use number_format function to print numbers with two digits after dot

Comment: Is the question about the DB storage or the simplexml usage? If DB storage we need to see the db scheme, how you are storing it, and what it writes as.

Comment: @chris85 it's not related to db storage, all to do with PHP. I think I can use the number_format function to force 2 decimal points.